# Git Plugin for Oh-My-ZSH broken after Updating Git

Tags: git, zsh, homebrew, zshrc

I was using the system version of git and then updated to the latest version using homebrew. After doing so, all the git shortcuts provided by the oh-my-zsh git plugin stopped working. I tried reinstalling oh-my-zsh but don't really know what else to do.

The only other thing I've changed is that I recently installed hub but I have not aliased it yet.

Comment: Do you mean the aliases such as `gst` (`git status`)? What does `which git` and `which <broken-shortcut>` return?

Comment: Yeah all the aliases provided by the git plugin like gst, gco (git checkout), etc are broken. which git returns /usr/local/bin/git and which gst returns gst not found... other plugins, like rails, still work

Comment: What does `alias | grep git` return? Do you see the aliases listed there?

Comment: No I don't. It shows the git alias' that I wrote in my .zshrc file but none of the alias' from the plugin

Comment: That sounds like either `oh-my-zsh` isn't being sourced, or the `git` section of the `oh-my-zsh` files isn't being sourced. Do you have a line similar to `source ~/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh` in your `~/.zshrc`?  Does your `~/.zshrc` have `plugins=(git)` in it?

Comment: The file that should contain all the `git` alias' is `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh`: [online here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh), (assuming you haven't installed somewhere other than `$HOME`). You could also check that that file exists in your `oh-my-zsh` installation (it should, unless you removed it).

Comment: Well if oh-my-zsh wasn't being sourced, I don't think the rails plugin would work. The git plugin is in the correct location. I do have a line that sources oh-my-zsh... I think something happened specifically to the git plugin when I upgraded to git using brew (from system git) because it worked before the update

Comment: you're right, even though oh-my-zsh was being sourced, the git plugin was not being sourced... would adding source ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh be the best solution? Post as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I had a different problem. I thought my zsh git autocompletion was broken. When I was trying to do `git add *.java` it said `no command found`. Finally I figured it out I was supposed to do `git add "*.java"` to add files. I'm new to `zsh`, so adding this as a comment hoping this might help someone.

Comment: I found someting really weird in my `.zshrc` file, the plugins were separated by comas and then after stripping off the comas everything worked, so making sure I am always using `plugins=(git osx docker)` format did the trick!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

From the comments, the `oh-my-zsh` plugin containing the `git` aliases isn't being sourced.

To do fix this, you can either:

1. Directly source the plugin by adding `source ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh` to your `~/.zshrc`,
2. Enable the plugin the canonical way: by adding `git` to the `plugins=(...)` line in `~/.zshrc`: `plugins=(git osx ruby)`. Note: my understanding is that, if you have two lines with `plugins=()`, the second will overwrite the first - I think (untested) that `plugins=($plugins git)` allows for enabling of plugins over multiple lines.

Comment: `source ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh` works for me. Has anyone reported this to oh-my-zhs?

Comment: adding `source ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh` to `~/.zshrc` worked for me. Also for plugins, I converted into a single line. Works like charm.

Comment: Worked. What changed? In my previous setups I did not need to set that line explicitly.

Answer (score 75):

To load zsh plugins default format as specified in .zshrc is `plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)`. For some reason it was written in this format `plugins=(git, lighthouse)` separated by comma. 
Separating just by space and source the .zshrc after saving fixed the issue.

Comment: I had the very same problem, in my default settings it contained commas and after the last update it broke things.

Comment: it was simply a matter of removing the commas

Comment: This was the answer for me.

Comment:  pretty obvious once you see it.

Comment: First usage and you see this, you run away